# How to reset or uncheckvalue of radio button with same name

Tags: javascript, java, html

I am trying to make a MCQ quiz question, where each question carries 4 options. I want to put individual reset button for each questions. When i click on reset button it reset or uncheck all radio button. How to reset radio button of same group or name?

```
<div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-9">
                        <div class="lms_service_detail">
                            <h3>An object is represented by two attributes, out of which one is characteristics and the other one is ___________.</h3>
                            <p><input name="1" id="Radio1" type="radio" value="A" /> Behaviour</p>
                            <p><input name="1" id="Radio2" type="radio" value="B" /> Situation</p>
                            <p><input name="1" id="Radio3" type="radio" value="C" /> Abstraction</p>
                            <p><input name="1" id="Radio4" type="radio" value="D" /> Encapsulation</p>
                            <p><input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Reset" /></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-9">
                        <div class="lms_service_detail">
                            <h3>Name the programming technique that implements programs as an organized collection of interactive objects.</h3>
                            <p><input name="2" id="Radio5" type="radio" value="A" /> Procedural Programming</p>
                            <p><input name="2" id="Radio6" type="radio" value="B" /> Modular Programming</p>
                            <p><input name="2" id="Radio7" type="radio" value="C" /> Object-Oriented Programming</p>
                            <p><input name="2" id="Radio8" type="radio" value="D" /> None of these</p>
                            <p><input id="Submit2" type="submit" value="Reset" /></p>
                        </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function onResetClick() {
    var $firstQuestion = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=1]');
    var $secondQuestion = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=2]');

    for (var i = 0; i < $firstQuestion.length; i++) {
        var $el = $firstQuestion;
        $el.setAttribute('checked', false);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < $secondQuestion.length; i++) {
        $el = $secondQuestion;
        $el.setAttribute('checked', false);
    }
}
```

Binding the onResetClick method will first get all the inputs corresponding to the questions. Then, we iterate over the elements and setAttribute checked as false. No jQuery required.

Answer (score 0):

In JQuery you can use:

```
$('input[name=Choose]').attr('checked',false); //for a specific radio button

OR

$('input').attr('checked',false); //for all radio buttons
```

And In JavaScript:

```
var ele = document.getElementsByName("Choose");
ele.checked = false; //for specific element

OR

var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i=0;i<inputs .length;i++)
  inputs [i].checked = false; //for all radio buttons
```